# MultipartException and IOFileUploadException when requests receives MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, tomcat, multipartfile

I'm developing a spring API and I have an endpoint that receives a MultipartFile as parameter but in the production environment I'm receiving the following error in some cases:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. java.io.EOFException

I'm using spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.4.7 that uses tomcat:9.0.46

I'm having some difficulty to debug this error because it throws before the code starts so it never reaches the logs that I put.

Thank you.
Regards.

Comment: Try turning on debug logging for Spring MVC by adding this to application.properties file "logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this does not happen all the time and only sometimes, its probably because the upload got interrupted ( browser got closed for example ). Therefore, there is nothing for you to change in the code.

You can get more details if you enable Spring MVC debug logging

**application.properties**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

Here's [additional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740378/failed-to-parse-multipart-servlet-request-when-file-uploading-interrupted) info about how you can efficiently log these kinds of errors.

Comment: Hi Arthur, I did some tests and this is exactly the cause of the problem. Apparently, the client is closing the application before the file is read. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Any time, bro ;)